# Get user geo-location in Blazor with JSInterop

Tags: javascript, geolocation, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I'm trying to get the user's city location, but first I want to try coordinates, as I find this hard enough already.

I have this javascript (from another post) but changed the return value;

```
<script>
window.getCoords = async () => {            
    const pos = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
    });
        return (pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
    };
</script>
```

Assuming, I will get `(double latitude, double longitude)` back (correct me if I'm wrong).
Also, I am not sure what the `Promise` keyword stands for, I'm assuming It's an old way for async...

After declaring this javascript in my `_Host.cshtml` file I go to my razor component.
The component has the following;

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@using BrowserInterop.Geolocation;
protected override async Task<(double latitude, double longitude)> OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{

    if (firstRender)
    {
        var location = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<(double longitude, double lattitude)>("getCoords");
        Console.WriteLine("Lat: " + test.lattitude, " Long: " + test.longitude);

    }
//If geo-location fails default to IP-based location (this method works fine)
    return await GetIpGeolocationAsync();
}
```

However, once my program runs it crashes once it gets to `var location = ...` and I don't get the user location or an error to resolve this matter.

I have searched multiple examples, but all end up the same way.
The [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-7.0) also don't give an example on this, any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a service to call my js.

`Coordinate.cs`

```
public struct Coordinate
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public double Accuracy { get; set; }
}
```

`geoLocationJsInterop.js`

```js
export function getCurrentPosition(dotNetHelper, enableHighAccuracy, maximumAge) {

    const options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: enableHighAccuracy,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: maximumAge
    };

    function success(position) {

        const coordinate = {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            accuracy: position.coords.accuracy
        };

        dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('OnSuccessAsync', coordinate);
    }

    function error(error) {

        const errorDetails = {
            errorCode: error.code,
            errorMessage: error.message
        };

        dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('OnErrorAsync', errorDetails);
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
}
```

`GeoLocationBroker.cs`

```cs
public class GeoLocationBroker : IGeoLocationBroker
{
    private readonly IJSRuntime jsRuntime;
    private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask;
    private readonly DotNetObjectReference<GeoLocationBroker> dotNetObjectReference;

    public GeoLocationBroker(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        this.jsRuntime = jsRuntime;

        moduleTask = new(() => this.jsRuntime!.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
            identifier: "import",
            args: "./scripts/geoLocations/geoLocationJsInterop.js")
        .AsTask());

        dotNetObjectReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
    }

    public async ValueTask RequestGeoLocationAsync(bool enableHighAccuracy, int maximumAgeInMilliseconds)
    {
        var module = await moduleTask.Value;
        var dotNetObjectReference = this.dotNetObjectReference;

        await module.InvokeVoidAsync(identifier: "getCurrentPosition",
                                     dotNetObjectReference,
                                     enableHighAccuracy,
                                     maximumAgeInMilliseconds);
    }

    public async ValueTask RequestGeoLocationAsync()
    {
        await RequestGeoLocationAsync(enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAgeInMilliseconds: 0);
    }

    public event Func<Coordinate, ValueTask> CoordinatesChanged = default!;

    public event Func<GeolocationPositionError, ValueTask> OnGeolocationPositionError = default!;

    [JSInvokable]
    public async Task OnSuccessAsync(Coordinate coordinates)
    {
        await CoordinatesChanged.Invoke(coordinates);
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public async Task OnErrorAsync(GeolocationPositionError error)
    {
        await OnGeolocationPositionError.Invoke(error);
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IGeoLocationBroker, GeoLocationBroker>();
```

[image]